# java.util.Random NextDouble() is biased towards higher uniform number

Tags: java, random

I am using `NextDouble()` to generate uniform random number. I generated random number with 500 different seeds and found that the generated uniform random number is biased towards higher uniform number (mean was 0.93). Which is very absurd. I then divided the seed by 10000 and the random number generated was perfect (mean was 0.51). 
I found that the seed should not be more than 48 bits and so made sure that the seed I provide (seed for `NextDouble()` is generated randomly using nextLong() with seed = 12345) is less 48 bits. Then I re-generated the random number 500 times and found the same problem. Does anyone had similar issues with `NextDouble()`?

Please see the code below:

```
Random randObject = new Random();

randObject.setSeed(12345);

long[] seed = new long[501];
for (int i = 1; i<=500; i++)
seed[i] = (long)( ( randObject.nextLong() / (double)Long.MAX_VALUE ) * Math.pow( 2, 48 ) ); // to make sure seed is not more than 48 bits

for (int i = 1; i<=500; i++)
{
  randObject.setSeed(seed[i]);
  randObject.nextDouble();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your test code.  It's more likely that you've made a mistake than that nextDouble is broken and no one noticed.

Comment: I did a quick test with 10000 seeds (0 to 10000) generating 500 random doubles per seed. Total average: ~ 0.5589. Looks fine so far. (Update: 100000/1000 has an average of ~ 0.505)

Comment: Random randObject = new Random();

randObject.setSeed(12345);

long[] seed = new long[500];
for (int i = 1; i<=500; i++)
seed[i] = (long)( ( randObject.nextLong() / (double)Long.MAX_VALUE ) * Math.pow( 2, 48 ) ); // to make sure seed is not more than 48 bits

for (int i = 1; i<=500; i++)
{
randObject.setSeed(seed[i]);
randObject.nextDouble();
}

Comment: Does your code run? `seed[i]` and `i <=500` won't work well together.

Comment: I wrote a snippet of the long code here as a summary of my problem. Sorry for the typo there.

Comment: Hmm, your code gives an average of ~0.48 for me.

Comment: Your sample shows with the limitation of 48 bits. What seed calculation do you use when you see the bias?

Comment: Please post a full example code, including the mean calculation, which shows the problem.

Comment: The code you've posted generates 500 double values with an average of about 0.48 and a mean of 0.46. If you manage to see a mean of 0.93, your mean calculation is incorrect.

Comment: Why are you always setting a new seed?

Comment: It is a part of the monte carlo simulation where each record gets a unique random seed and then a uniform number is drawn for that record. The same record with the unique seed is used several times for different simulations.

Comment: Well, Java does guarantee a that those numbers have pseudo-random properties accross one flow of seed, not accross first numbers of various seeds (even though they can be randomly seeded).

Answer (score 2):

"...I generated [a] random number with 500 different seeds..."

That's your problem. A random number generator generates a *sequence* of numbers from a given seed, that, *taken as a sequence*, are random and uniformly distributed. If you only take the first number from the sequence, there are no such guarantees. In fact, an RNG might decide to return the seed itself as its first value--that would be perfectly valid. In practice, they generally hash the seed somehow.

So your 500 numbers are not a random sequence at all. They are simply a hash function of your input seeds, and there's no reason whatsoever to expect them to be random.

Answer (score 1):

The Java-8 version seems to offer a different picture:

```
public void test() {
    Random r1 = new Random();
    Random r2 = new Random();

    r1.setSeed(12345);
    double average = IntStream.range(0, 5000)
            // 5000 random longs.
            .mapToLong(i -> r1.nextLong())
            // Used as seeds to a Random
            .mapToDouble(l -> {
                r2.setSeed(l);
                return r2.nextDouble();
            })
            // Gather stats.
            .summaryStatistics()
            // Average,
            .getAverage();
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
}
```

Prints `0.5000...` fairly consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations

> I found that the seed should not be more than 48 bits and so made sure that the seed I provide (seed for NextDouble() is generated randomly using nextLong() with seed = 12345) is less 48 bits.

You proved experimentally that `java.util.Random` is 48bit LCG generator

From its sources

`48:  * The algorithm is described in <em>The Art of Computer Programming,
  49:  * Volume 2</em> by Donald Knuth in Section 3.2.1.  It is a 48-bit seed,
  50:  * linear congruential formula.
  51:  *`

link http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Random` is a [linear congruential generator (LCG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which propagates the next state from the current state.  You're using the output of an LCG to seed itself, so each of your seeds is going to be related to the outputs produced by the other seeds.  From that point on, all bets are off as to the distributional behavior of the results.

Seed your 500 streams from `/dev/random`, or with the output of an entirely different class of generator such as a [feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) or [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).  Then, if you're still observing bias, write up a journal paper.